# How to pass member function as a parameter

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a dynamic spell system for a game I'm developing: spells should consist of an archetype, e.g. area of effect and an effect, e.g. heal.

I have following (simplified) code:

```
class SpellEffect {
public:
    virtual void heal(int magnitude);
}

class SpellArchetype {
public:
    virtual void applyToArea(int sizeOfArea, void (*func)(int));
}

class Spell {
    SpellEffect effect;
    SpellArchetype archetype;
    int sizeOfArea;
    int magnitude;
public:
    void cast() {
        archetype.applyToArea(sizeOfArea, &effect.heal);
    }
}
```

However, since `heal()` is a member function this does not work.

I also have trouble passing the argument `magnitude` to the `heal()` function.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020174/how-to-properly-pass-member-function-as-a-parameter) question and the answer seems helpful. Yet it has been a while since I last used C++ and I can't figure out how to make it work in my case since the `this` is different.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be as shown below. Note that you can also use `std::function`.

```
class SpellEffect {
public:
    virtual void heal(int magnitude);
};

class SpellArchetype {
public:
//-------------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---->func is a pointer to a member function of class SpellEffect that has one int parameter and return type of void
    virtual void applyToArea(int sizeOfArea, void (SpellEffect::*func)(int));
};

class Spell {
    SpellEffect effect;
    SpellArchetype archetype;
    int sizeOfArea;
    int magnitude;
public:
    void cast() {
//----------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---->correct syntax instead of &effect.heal
        archetype.applyToArea(sizeOfArea, &SpellEffect::heal);
    }
};
```

In the above code, instead of having `void (*func)(int)` we have:

```
void (SpellEffect::*func)(int)
```

which means that `func` is a pointer to a member function of class `SpellEffect` that takes one `int` parameter and has the return type of `void`.